# Pyramid chart titles bolded and do not show full text

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highcharts to create a pyramid chart.  The chart itself is created and the data looks fine, but it looks ugly.  Specifically, the names of the sections of the pyramid are bolded and the full name is not displayed.  How do I fix this?

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript">risk_pyramid_chart = new Highcharts.Chart({"chart":{"type":"pyramid","marginRight":"100","renderTo":"risk_pyramid_chart"},"title":{"text":null},"credits":{"enabled":false},"plotOptions":{"series":{"dataLabels":{"enabled":true,"format":"<b>{point.name}<\/b> ({point.y:,.0f})","color":"(Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'","softConnector":true}},"pyramid":{"colors":["orange","orangered"]}},"legend":{"enabled":false},"series":[{"name":"Risk Pyramid","data":[["Medium",3],["High",23]]}]});</script>
```

Here's a jsfiddle with the code:

https://jsfiddle.net/9obqdcn0/

I would expect to see the full names of each of the levels of the pyramid as well as the names not bolded like they are.  This is how it used to be and I think it changed when we updated our version of HighCharts at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see full data-labels, you need to adapt the `series.width` property which is set to 90% by default. The bold effect results from the wrong format of `color` setting.

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      width: '60%',
      "dataLabels": {
        color: 'black',
        ...
      }
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4ea25nj1/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pyramid.width

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pyramid.dataLabels.color

Comment: Thanks for the answer @ppotaczek!  The color definitely fixed that part.  On the wording, I found the dataLabels.crop property and set it to false, which now shows the entire word.  Appreciate your help with this!